# Delphi Замена иконки в ехе

Tags: delphi, icon

Долго гуглил примеры замены иконки (думал, что тема уже заезженная), единственный более-менее рабочий пример

```
function EnumLangsFunc(hModule: Cardinal; lpType, lpName: PAnsiChar;
wLanguage: Word; lParam: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
PWord(lParam)^ := wLanguage;
Result := False;
end;

function GetResourceLanguage(hModule: Cardinal; lpType, lpName: PAnsiChar;
var wLanguage: Word): Boolean;
begin
wLanguage := 0;
EnumResourceLanguages(hModule, lpType, lpName, @EnumLangsFunc,Integer(@wLanguage));
Result := True;
end;

procedure updateIcons(const fileName, icoFileName: string);
type
  PIcoItemHeader = ^TIcoItemHeader; 
  TIcoItemHeader = packed record 
    Width: byte;
    Height: byte;
    Colors: byte;
    Reserved: byte;
    Planes: word;
    BitCount: word;
    ImageSize: dword;
  end;

  PIcoItem = ^TIcoItem;
  TIcoItem = packed record
    Header: TIcoItemHeader;
    Offset: dword;
  end;

  PIcoHeader = ^TIcoHeader; 
  TIcoHeader = packed record 
    Reserved: word;
    Typ: word;
    ItemCount: word;
    Items: array [0..MaxInt shr 4 - 1] of TIcoItem; 
  end;

  PGroupIconDirItem = ^TGroupIconDirItem; 
  TGroupIconDirItem = packed record 
    Header: TIcoItemHeader; 
    Id: word;
  end;

  PGroupIconDir = ^TGroupIconDir;
  TGroupIconDir = packed record
    Reserved: word;
    Typ: word;
    ItemCount: word;
    Items: array [0..MaxInt shr 4 - 1] of TGroupIconDirItem;
  end;

var
  ch: char;
  H: THandle;
  M: HMODULE;
  R: HRSRC;
  Res: HGLOBAL;
  GroupIconDir, NewGroupIconDir: PGroupIconDir;
  I: integer;
  wLanguage: word;
  FS: TFileStream;
  Ico: PIcoHeader;
  N: cardinal;
  NewGroupIconDirSize: longint;
begin

  Ico:=nil;
  GroupIconDir:=nil;
  try
    fs:=TFileStream.Create(IcoFileName,fmOpenRead,fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      N:=fs.Size;
      GetMem(Ico, N);
      fs.Read(Ico^,N)
    finally
      fs.Free
    end;
    H:=BeginUpdateResource(pChar(FileName), false);
    try 
      M:=LoadLibraryEx(PChar(FileName), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
      try
        R := FindResource(M, 'MAINICON', RT_GROUP_ICON);
        if r <> 0 then
        begin
          GetResourceLanguage(M, RT_GROUP_ICON, 'MAINICON', wLanguage);
          Res:=LoadResource(M, R);
          GroupIconDir:=LockResource(Res);
          UpdateResource(H, RT_GROUP_ICON, 'MAINICON', wLanguage, nil, 0);
          for I:=0 to GroupIconDir.ItemCount-1 do
          begin
            wLanguage:=GetSystemDefaultLangID;
            UpdateResource(H, RT_ICON, MakeIntResource(GroupIconDir.Items[I].Id), wLanguage, nil, 0);          end;
          NewGroupIconDirSize:=3*SizeOf(word)+Ico.ItemCount*sizeOf(TGroupIconDirItem);
          GetMem(NewGroupIconDir, NewGroupIconDirSize);
          try
            NewGroupIconDir.Reserved:=GroupIconDir.Reserved;
            NewGroupIconDir.Typ:=GroupIconDir.Typ;
            NewGroupIconDir.ItemCount:=Ico.ItemCount;
            for I:=0 to NewGroupIconDir.ItemCount-1 do
              begin
                NewGroupIconDir.Items[I].Header:=Ico.Items[I].Header;
                NewGroupIconDir.Items[I].Id:=I+1
              end;
            for I:=0 to NewGroupIconDir.ItemCount-1 do
              UpdateResource(H, RT_ICON, MakeIntResource(NewGroupIconDir.Items[I].Id),              wLanguage, Pointer(DWORD(Ico) + Ico.Items[I].Offset), Ico.Items[I].Header.ImageSize);              UpdateResource(H, RT_GROUP_ICON, 'MAINICON', wLanguage, NewGroupIconDir, NewGroupIconDirSize);
          finally
            FreeMem(NewGroupIconDir)
          end;
          end;
        finally
          FreeLibrary(M)
        end;
    except
      EndUpdateResource(H, true);
      raise
    end;
    EndUpdateResource(H, False);
  finally
    FreeMem(Ico)
  end;
end;
```

Но заменяет иконки не у всех ЕХЕ, можете подсказать, в чем проблема ? или посоветовать рабочий пример

Comment: "заменяет далеко не все иконки" - это что? Насколько далеко?

Comment: @Igor образное выражение )) что значит "заменяет не у всех иконки", простите, если не так выразился

Comment: Теперь гораздо понятнее, что происходит.

Comment: @Igor можете помочь ?

Comment: Когда-то давно, выясняя про иконки exe-файлов, я сделал для себя вывод, что Windows показывает первую по алфавиту иконку. То есть MAINICON Вы может и заменяете, но на то, как файл показывается в Windows Explorer-e, это не влияет.

Comment: @Igor вы имеете в виду кэширование ? я переносил файл, но иконка по прежнему оставалась старой

Comment: Нет, кэширование я не имел в виду. Посмотрите в каком-нибудь редакторе ресурсов - есть ли в тех exe-файлах, которые остались со старыми иконками, другие ресурсы типа ICON - кроме MAINICON.

Comment: @Igor и что в таком случае делать ? заменить все иконки ? или прежде удалить все, а потом поставить свою ? такое возможно ?

Comment: Подождите, давайте сначала убедимся, что дело именно в этом.

Comment: @Igor нет, дело не в этом http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/12/24/0003/1069/205869/69/e81d0b864a.jpg всего одна иконка, но не заменило

Comment: да и странно, в тех ЕХЕ, где заменяет, имя этого ехе переходит в верхний регистр и в конце файла добавляются байты "...DINGPADDINGXXPAD" (в текстовом формате привел)

Comment: @Igor есть идеи ?

Comment: а зачем вообще заменять чужие иконки?